# Performance trouble with xunit tests on regex-based parser

Tags: .net, regex, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

I have a very simple regex-based parser. Parser extracts some specific key-value pairs from plain text. It takes about 10ms per plain text document. Average document length is about 700 bytes, biggest document found is ~2kb.

Everything work fine until unit tests run.

Most of tests run fast (from build to build graph from build server):

[image: most of tests]

Some of tests occasionally run fast:

[image: occasionally fast]

But some of them stuck for a minutes:

[image: so slooooow]

The only difference between unit tests is document's text and object to be compared to result. And order in which they run.

When I run this code manually (e.g. in console app), it runs extremely fast compared to unit test (10ms vs 2.5min).

Profiling test runner exposed that most of time consumed by regex - Regex.Scan method. Looking a bit deeper I found following:

[image]

JIT compilation? Seems like RegexOptions.Compiled option affected.
When this option was removed, tests run fast.

So my questing is why regex compilation takes so much time when run in test runner (either on build server or locally)? And why it always run fast otherwise (console app with exactly same code never took more then 2 seconds from start to end)?

Regexes are very simple, e.g.: `(?:^\s*(?<property>Some|option(?:s and names)?|of|keys)\s*[\s:=-](?:(?!\r?\n)\s)*(?<value>(?:(?!\r?\n).)*)(?:(?!\r?\n)\s)*(?:\r?\n|$))`

Unit tests are implemented with xUnit 2.0, .NET 4.5, AnyCPU, Release build, x64 machine.

**Update** Profiling console app with same code:

[image]

Comment: Just a note: I do not think a tempered greedy token is considered a simple regex pattern. :) You also have a lot of alternations, and that means backtracking. When you need to use regexps heavily, place them into a static class and let them initialize during app start. Then, they will perform faster during the app execution.

Comment: @stribizhev Yep, this is quite greedy regex. However it fits out needs. And no one want to touch them. :) In production it starts fast. About ~90ms on first regex call and ~10ms on subsequent calls. It takes 2 minutes only when run in xunit runner.

Comment: Without actual test case and regex, it's hard to tell what is the problem here. Please include a reproducible regex + test case in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what `RegexOptions.Compiled` actually does. This function causes the `RegEx` object to create a couple of runtime generated internal methods. So it actually creates MSIL code and compiles this at runtime into methods.

This takes a **really** long time during the construction of the object. Once the object is finished it is usually slightly faster in parsing regular expressions and uses slightly less memory.

How ever usually you need to run hundreds of strings though this expression to gain anything at all, because the initial compilation takes so long.

Comment: I understand what `RegexOptions.Compiled` will lead to. But.. 2 minutes for small dynamic assembly generation and compilation? And only when run by xunit test runner? I just measured time with `RegexOptions.Compiled` in same code from console app. Result is ~90ms on first call to regex.

Comment: Okay. Is your normal console app also using the `compatjit`?

Comment: No. Look to **update** in question. With profiler attached it runs a bit slower :)

Comment: So why is the xunit runner activating the `compatjit`? Is there any config file for the xunit runner that contains something like `<useLegacyJit enabled="1" />` ?

Comment: Good question. There is nothing of that in config. I think I need to address this question to xUnit developers. What is `compatjit` at all? How it differs from `clrjit`?

Comment: It worth to mention that runner grows up to 1.2gb of memory while that simple regex compiling with `compatjit`. And there is different runners - xUnit on build server and JetBrans runner when run from Visual Studio. Both result to `jitcompat`.

Comment: The `compatjit` is the 64bit just-in-time compiler of .NET that was replaced by the new RyuJIT in .NET 4.6. Have you installed .NET 4.6? Or is the xunit running in 64bit and the console in 32bit?